# data reload after ajax done() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I try to reload popup cart data
here is a functions

```
    if (!BIS.updateTopCartFromCart) {
        BIS.updateTopCartFromCart = {
            init: function() {
                ajax_block('.top-cart');
                ajax_load('.top-cart', '<?=$arResult['AJAX_CALL_ID']?>', $('.top-cart-form').serializeArray());
            }
        }
    }
    if (!BIS.updatePopupTopCart) {
        BIS.updatePopupTopCart = {
            init: function() {
                var container = $('#popup-cart-wrapper');
                var defUpdatedTopCart = new $.Deferred();

                ajax_block('.top-cart');
                var ajaxEnded = ajax_load('.top-cart', '<?=$arResult['AJAX_CALL_ID']?>', $('.top-cart-form').serializeArray());
                $.when(ajaxEnded).done(function() {
                    defUpdatedTopCart.resolve();
                    $.fancybox({
                        content: container,
                        afterLoad: function(){
                            container.html($('.popup')).fadeIn('fast');
                            container.show();
                        }
                    });

                });
                return defUpdatedTopCart;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
 BIS.cartPopup = {
            init: function(container) {
                var cartPopupLink = $('.buttCart');
                var self = this;
}
}
```

and here is cartUpdate function:

```
updateCart: function() {
            var container = $('#popup-cart-wrapper');
            ajax_block('#basket-form');
            var ajaxEnded2 = ajax_load('#basket-form', '<?=$arResult['AJAX_CALL_ID']?>', $('#basket-form').serializeArray());
            $.when(ajaxEnded2).done(function(){
                BIS.cartPopup.init('#popup-cart-wrapper');
                BIS.updateTopCartFromCart.init();
                BIS.updatePopupTopCart.init();
            })
        }
```

ajax returns right data, but I don't understand,  why it doesn't reload popup data.
if I correct understand It has to do it, after done() function, but it doesn't
what I missed
help me pleace
best reguards!
here is ajax_load function:

```
function ajax_load (container, ajax_call, params, append) {
    if (!$.isArray(params)) {
        params = $.queryString(params);
    }
    $.post(
        '/bitrix/tools/ajax.php?ajax_call='+ajax_call,
        params,
        function (data) {
            if (container) {
                if (append) {
                    $(container).append(data);
                } else {
                    $(container).html(data);
                }
            }
        }
    );
    //return false;
}
```

Comment: Try yo add an `alert` after this line: `$.when(ajaxEnded2).done(function(){` is this alert shows up? This check if the `ajax`'s callback is firing at all. Also, which library are you using? (I don't now `ajax_load` function in `jQuery` - for example)

Comment: @MoshFeu ajax_load function ajax_load (container, ajax_call, params, append) {
 if (!$.isArray(params)) {
  params = $.queryString(params);
 }
 $.post(
  '/bitrix/tools/ajax.php?ajax_call='+ajax_call,
  params,
  function (data) {
   if (container) {
                if (append) {
                    $(container).append(data);
                } else {
                    $(container).html(data);
                }
   }
  }
 );
 //return false;
} alert is shows

Comment: Can you please add this code to the question (and all of the relevant code)? Do you know how to edit your question?

Comment: I would rather suggest you add a Delegate param to your ajax_load function where you can send in a function and if it exists evaluate it. I have run in to numerous problems where having the correct execution context in a ajax call is key. You can then pass the code you wanted to use in the .done function to your ajax load and it should get called after your ajax call has happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to happen:

```
var ajaxEnded = ajax_load('.top-cart',...);
```

you must return promise from your function:

```
function ajax_load (container, ajax_call, params, append) {
    if (!$.isArray(params)) {
        params = $.queryString(params);
    }
    var promise = $.post(
        '/bitrix/tools/ajax.php?ajax_call='+ajax_call,
        params,
        function (data) {
            if (container) {
                if (append) {
                    $(container).append(data);
                } else {
                    $(container).html(data);
                }
            }
        }
    );
    return promise;
}
```